# TypeScript type error when using generic callbacks for different event types

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm trying to make some kind of a generic event handler, I want to be able to specify the event key like "pointermove" and typescript to infer the event type in this case PointerEvent, but I get an error when using more than one event.

here's a minimal repoducible [example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FDCmA8AcHsCcBcAE8CelSIMLQHbwIYCWOoAJgKIBuoeAPIgNKITw2kDOiA1qCtAGaIAEgBUAsgBlyAG1ABbGvCqKx+SAD5EAXkQBvYIkPNqeAHL4FALkYBuA0YDG+adIBG+B12vY8REhRN4TGc3Dy56BnU7Q2AAXzsIGARkNAwfAmIyZTxgl3dPCOZwVhwObl4BYXEpWQU8bPhVDW1EAAp7Q1BA61FJGXlFBqaAbQYAXQAaEABKbU1KaEJSBKg4JFJQfnwAV2kkfm2cB3hCXERt9lB0vzIxXZPIWQAFAAt8S4baDsYikrKePiCXo1Ab1QJNFoAyrA-p1JTgtTAdTtIzMaQ9aqwxSIKaorqKdjeXAZfyfSLDSbAWb6VH2fhwNoOXDsJAYSr4vDsanfTrSAB0+FIAUUEkILJooFgrVAfI58HMCgmbS6sy0mhlTjyYWllGm02iiFiqMQcWATJwLMQpEIlBapGgDm2cL5DlgoHwrCxeFaACJrZQffqDObLfaAIJE3yZYU5EL5cI+mDEViwe0AdxwPs0OhRxs6uKMqs0NONIegsj50mgAHNfWHA994sHmetoAAhSMkrKBXKhAqJxZ4SVyaDULMtXN50AFwxFvQ8xBlitV2s+tsN1FN4AXK7Em6kO57QiPUCvd6gBqtf0z43DBd5kt5p-GRQK0DWAfJyXpzM35+ozU+y8K1oDDP8n1icCH3vf85TfD8kyHWARzHKD-0A+NrHtNs0M3GCxm+INgCAA)

```ts
export type ContainedEvent< K extends keyof HTMLElementEventMap> = {
    eventName: K;
    callback: ContainedEventCallback< K>;
  
};
export type ContainedEventCallback< K extends keyof HTMLElementEventMap> = (
    event: HTMLElementEventMap[K],

) => void;
export default function useContainedMultiplePhaseEvent<
    K extends keyof HTMLElementEventMap = keyof HTMLElementEventMap
>(
    el: HTMLElement ,
    events: ContainedEvent<K>[],
) {
    
  for (const e of events) {
      el.addEventListener(e.eventName, (ev) => e.callback(ev));
  }     
}
const div = document.createElement("div");
 const doA: ContainedEventCallback<"pointerdown"> = (
        e,
    ) => {
      console.log("A")
    };
 const doB: ContainedEventCallback<"pointermove"> = (
        e,
    ) => {
      console.log("B")
    };

useContainedMultiplePhaseEvent(div,
        [
            {
                eventName: "pointerdown",
                callback: doA,
            },
            {
                eventName: "pointermove",
                callback: doB,
            }
        ]
    );
```

Comment: One issue is that TS infers an array element type from only the first element of an array literal; you could make your function generic in the *array* instead of the *element* like [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/we8KXW) shows and it would fix the problem you're having here.  There are other approaches too but they would require more refactoring.  Does this meet your needs? If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Yes that's what I need, I don't mind seeing other approaches too in fact I would be thankful. @jcalz

Comment: I am going to bed now but I will write up an answer when I wake up; not sure if I will go into too much detail about other approaches because then the answer will be ten pages long.  For example, you could make `ContainedEvent` a union like [this](https://tsplay.dev/Wyx9xm) and not need a generic `useContainedMultiplePhaseEvent`.  But I digress (and need to sleep)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the primary issue here is that when TypeScript infers a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) *element* type from [an array literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#array_literals), it only consults the first element of the array.  This is often what people want, since since it lets something like `function foo<T>(...args: T[]) {}` accept `foo("a", "b", "c")` and `foo(1, 2, 3)`, but reject `foo("a", 2, "c")`.  That is, when inferring `T` from a value of type `T[]`, the compiler will only infer *homogeneous* arrays.  But in your case you want to allow a *hetereogenous* array.

The normal approach in such cases is to change the generic type parameter so that it refers to the entire array and not just the element type of the array.  In your case that would mean instead of having `K` refer to the type argument for `ContainedEvent`, you could make it refer to the [tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types) of type arguments for a tuple of `ContainedEvent`s.  Meaning `K` would be something like `["pointerdown", "pointermove"]` and `events` would be of type `[ContainedEvent<"pointerdown">, ContainedEvent<"pointermove">]`.

Like this:

```
function useContainedMultiplePhaseEvent<K extends readonly (keyof HTMLElementEventMap)[]>(
    el: HTMLElement, events: [...{ [I in keyof K]: ContainedEvent<K[I]> }],
) {
    for (const e of events) {
        el.addEventListener(e.eventName, (ev) => e.callback(ev));
    }
}
```

so the type of `events` is a [mapped tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html#mapped-types-on-tuples-and-arrays) where each element of `K` at numeric-like index `I`, of type `K[I]`, is wrapped with `ContainedEvent` to get `ContainedEvent<K[I]>`.  Oh and the type of `events` is wrapped in a [variadic tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#variadic-tuple-types) `[...⋯]` to give the compiler a hint that we want `events`'s type to be inferred as a tuple instead of an unordered array (this behavior is described in [ms/TS#39094](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/39094)).

Let's try it out:

```
useContainedMultiplePhaseEvent(div, [
    { eventName: "pointerdown", callback: doA, },
    { eventName: "pointermove", callback: doB, }
]); // okay
// useContainedMultiplePhaseEvent<["pointerdown", "pointermove"]>
```

Looks good!

---

That answers the question as asked.

There are other possible approaches but I didn't want to stray too far from your original code.  Since `K` in `ContainedEvent<K>` can only really be one of a fixed [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) `keyof HTMLElementEventMap`, you could actually make `ContainedEvent` into a union itself, possibly by changing the definition to a *distributive object type* as described in [ms/TS#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109).  Then your `useContainedMultiplePhaseEvent` function wouldn't need to be generic, since each element of `events` would just be of the union type `ContainedEvent`.  That looks like this:

```
type ContainedEvent<K extends keyof HTMLElementEventMap = keyof HTMLElementEventMap> =
    { [P in K]: {
        eventName: P; callback: ContainedEventCallback<P>;
    } }[K];

function useContainedMultiplePhaseEvent(el: HTMLElement, events: ContainedEvent[]) {
    events.forEach(<K extends keyof HTMLElementEventMap>(e: ContainedEvent<K>) =>
        el.addEventListener(e.eventName, (ev) => e.callback(ev)));
}
```

which also works as desired.  You can look at ms/TS#47109 to see how a distributive object type works; otherwise I won't digress here with a detailed explanation.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAOwhgtgpgzgDmAxlABAWTHOUAmBBAJwLAE8UBvYYFGlAFxOxQGEB7EOsASxFwFEAblA4AeANIooADzrCcMFAGsoJVgDMUACQAqaADJ8ANlGgdBwuhjgA+FAF4K1Ws6hCOAOUhQAXCjEBuJ2caRDBDQwAjJEVfNg5uXhxzDmYwyOjxa0DnAF9s2gYmOM4efjc6VPCoxEVxSRk5BWVVDR19IxMLZMtMWwcAClcLXzaDY1M6bqsAbTEAXQBKe1sBVi4cfJo1AFcQRDoudhRtmChihNw0bcMDuGMABQALMFPuuulZEHkUAigwHHYhjI-Wa6i0ujGnTM5SsC2mc2s-SCwSghhGEI6EwANJJyjBfNMAHTE8goaYASRQPCUKjB81i7BKiTeYgpCJQOTmWORS0owVoalYBBQ-UQ7BgdEkKDBQw4MF5yP5NFRhP+SXKei4EuEUAIg0JsronmgOMGAiWdlsUEJoSq0TNCwWm2COWRruRYpAEpQOC4AnsPtYiG2ExtvzAskxFn6ACJfQIY06PeLJQC8Az4qV1RZKukaiIY3A1hxdQCAO4gGN9EWK2hQbnOC22PlKz0wVjGQmGVgAc1jeETbudbdTrAAQhmmWUc2lqrVC8XZAQIKwhFWA0ilZIG7Qm44t22O9bu32Y2PB7lAlRnCczoyLjgrjcuHcoE8XlBuv14zjprWaKShrGj4KALjwS7lpWOK2nmMSBngOI5Du-KAeUwG+GBJbLquUAxtBs7RL4AJjohyKLP4KAAPSUdKiikMi1HHKc5xZk+twPM8rzlCI0yYRBrAVnhoFFuBuormuCLAO64DQPASCoAAIlqdAEFwEQAPIRAAVlA+zaIwqCUNeBQGSw95Zt0uZzu8DRfE0tKtBi4xdDCvQbv+uLDOC7TOdCFgzPMyEoHuqzrFeyKFKgLHMtxEgfI0NItN5kITFMmABqCjk+VCkyuTY9geaS0z3FSIB+HMvgtluypoV4vj3BRMFzpOD6WQR+b3FkHk5BysxzFezg7HsBxHLe0WXNc7Fvpxn7lIMaLJVGHA4oa+JmZmMUWPCCpbqthKCgQfBII8-Q2Z83yZYtvm5f5vSDC1FmxdYTYeS4hiqjg2YcJq2q8Hq1pAV4pquHu1pNfaIOOs67rOCOPp+gGALBqGiDhpG12xvGibDim8EPZtKTtfOIlYZB64DFAe6koenYnv2iYcjjXqjhO61Tl9FREwWJNLuJuHVoMVMoDTx69rG55LHkxk0GN5mJGxL4cR+X4-mShWvXWtXQBhPOlgJUEayERNEawCHdUFzhVdVgPa8Ji5iTheGG8LxuBiR3VkUmVA5EAA)

Comment: Thank you very much that was very well articulated